# C++ program bad output

Tags: c++

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int a(){
    int formula = 20/30;
    return formula;
}

int d(){
    return a();
}

int main()
{

  cout<< d() <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have a program code above. For some reason program output is 0, but it should be 0.6

Comment: int formula = 20/30; // this will take the integer part of 20/30.use float

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: The return type for your function is `int`, so matter what you did inside that function, you were being returned an `int`.  So it's strange why you expected `0.6`.

Comment: `int` is for integers, it cannot hold a rational or real number?

Comment: A lot of newcomers to C++ have the notion that math is done like on a hand-held calculator, where the answer just comes out "correct".  This is not the case -- the data type(s) used play an important role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the data type that you have used (i.e. `int`). Checkout Corrected code (Because `int` can't store floating point numbers you need to change it to some other data type):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

float a(){
    float formula = 20/30;
    return formula;
}

float d(){
    return a();
}

int main()
{

  cout << d() <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You can also use `double` instead of `float`.